# Question on Converting ints to datetimes in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a stored procedure that takes an int for the desired month and year as parameters. It uses these to compare some datetime values from the tables I'm pulling from. I need to conver them into DateTime values. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(4), @year) + '-' + Convert(varchar(2),@month) + '-01 00:00:00', 102))
```

which builds the "2009-6-1 00:00:00" string (for those parameter values). This doesn't seem to work though, any other suggestions on how to do this? I think I'm going about this too much like a programmer...

This is Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4))  + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '01' AS DATETIME)
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
DECLARE @year int;
DECLARE @Month int;

SET @year = 2010;
SET @Month = 1

SELECT CAST(LTRIM(@year * 10000 + @Month * 100 + 1) AS smalldatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEADD`.

```
DATEADD(month, @month - 1, DATEADD(year, @year - 1900, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter dates using the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales
WHERE YEAR(Sales.PurchaseDate) = @year
AND MONTH(Sales.PurchaseDate) = @month
```